# Hide buttons when logged in

Tags: php, jquery, html

How do I hide my buttons "Inloggen" and "Registreren" when I am logged in? I have two seperate files; I have my index file with the menu etc and a inloggen file for the php and the form. If I am logged in I want the buttons to hide and replace it for a button with logout. How do I do that with my code?

Index:

```
<?php
require 'dbconnectie.php';
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>PC4U</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container1">
<header>
    <div id="headerFotoDiv">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="100px" class="lihover" onclick="window.location='http://www.pc4u.hexodo.nl/'">
    </div>
    <div id="headerLogindiv">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=i'" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">Inloggen</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=re'" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">Registreren</button>
    </div>

</header>
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="width: 1000px; margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;border-radius:0px; background-color:#FFFFFF;";>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px;">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true" style="height: 1px;padding:0px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li onclick="document.location.href='http://www.pc4u.hexodo.nl/'" class="lihover"><a>Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Computers
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="?p=dp">PC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?p=lp">Laptop</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="?p=r">Reparatie</a></li>
                <li><a href="?p=c">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="?p=w">Winkelwagen</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Vulling van de pagina -->
<div id="vulling">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $pagina = $_GET['p'];
    switch ($pagina) {
        case "c":
            include("contact.php");
            break;
        case "r":
            include("reparatie.php");
            break;
        case "re":
            include("registreren.php");
            break;
        case "i":
            include("inloggen.php");
            break;
        case "w":
            include("shoppingcart.php");
            break;
        case "ch":
            include("computerhome.php");
            break;
        case "lp":
            include("laptop.php");
            break;
        case "dp":
            include("desktop.php");
            break;
        default:
            include("home.php");
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    include("home.php");
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inloggen:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

//var_dump($_SESSION);
if(!isset($_POST['username']))
$_POST['username'] = '';
if(!isset($_POST['password']))
$_POST['password'] = '';

//if (isset($_SESSION['ingelogd'])&&$_SESSION ['ingelogd'] == true ) header("location: http://www.pc4u.hexodo.nl");

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "*****";
$dbpass = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$uname = $_POST['username'];
$wwoord = $_POST['password'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM Klanten WHERE klant_username = "' . $uname . '" && klant_wachtwoord = "' . $wwoord . '"';

$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {

    $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
    header("location: index.php");
} else {
    $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = false;
    $msg = "Inloggegevens incorrect.";
}
//$conn->close();
}
?>
<link href="contact.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
input, td, tr {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
</style>


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;" for="username">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="password" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" style="margin-left: 120px; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Inloggen</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:
        Just like in your login page check if the login session is set, if it is set show the logout button. If the login session is not set, display the 2 other buttons.

```
<div id="headerLogindiv">
<?php
    if($_SESSION['ingelogd']){
?>        
    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location=logout.php" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">Uitloggen</button>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=i'" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">Inloggen</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=re'" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">Registreren</button>
}
</div>
```

Or you could use Jquery to check if the session has been set. First give the login / registratie button a different class then the logout button. For example: class="inloggen" for the login / registration. and class="logout" for the uitlog button.  If it has been set `$('.inlogen').hide()` `$('.uitloggen').show()` visa versa

Answer (score 0):

**How do I hide my buttons "Inloggen" and "Registreren" when I am logged in?**

You should just check if the session is set for the user or not. i.e., If the session [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

If the session is set, you should show logout button

Else if the session is not set then you should show logout and register button.

**Here is what you should do**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']))
{
?>
   <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location=logout.php" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">Uitloggen</button>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
 <div id="headerLogindiv">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=i'" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">Inloggen</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=re'" style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">Registreren</button>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Suggestion :**

Never have the db connection in all your files, you can just have a file named as `config.php` or something and you can include where it is required.

**Tip for debugging :**

To print all the sessions

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Lol this is exactly the same answer as what I posted

Comment: That doesn't make it disappear. Even when logged in I keep seeing the buttons, and logout isnt appearing.

Comment: @AngelofDemons You can't change the theory 1+1=2. But i will try to add some uniqueness in my answer now :)

Comment: Then the session is probably not set properly @Lucafraser

Comment: @Lucafraser Can you try to print the session from your browser ?

Comment: First you should do debug like this Whether the credentials is right 1. $result->num_rows, 2. then whether the session is creating, by printing once it is created,. Was this positive in your case  ?